# Three20 project crash on jailbroken iPhone3G, works fine on 3GS without JB

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

i've got a strange problem: i've made a simple app using three20 framework, it builds without error, after installing the app on 3GS it works great, but after opening it on jailbroken 3G ot crashes with following errors:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).

warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileLoader.dylib" (file not found).
2010-10-06 16:11:26.744 TTTest6[1653:307] MS:Notice: Installing: com.funandmobile.bluetoothdemo [TTTest6] (550.38)

2010-10-06 16:11:26.886 TTTest6[1653:307] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib


warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib" (file not found).

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.
```

does anybody encountered similar problem?
thanks for any help

Mapedd

Comment: Too bad for jailbroken iPhone. It seems it doesn't find some librairies.

Answer (score 1):

You are crazy to try and support Jailbroken phones. My advice - stop now before you drive yourself crazy.  Apple frowns upon jailbreaking for many reasons, this being high on the list.  There are way too many possibilities of jailbroken configurations and setups that in order for apps to support them, they have to do tons of (normally) unnecessary checks and error prevention.

Comment: I'm not trying to support them , i simply first time saw this error, i was curious what's that.

Comment: So you are saying that it's nothing unusual , that there are weird problems with JB phones?

Comment: Yes jb phones mess with the way Apple normally expects things to be. Like libraries and system configuration. Don't get me wrong, I am all for freedom on the device and jb, but I also know that many apps will have failures when people JB without knowing what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is more likely to do with the fact that the iPhone 3G and 3GS use arm6 and arm7 respectively. The binary you're building is not compatible with the older 3G.

In the build for three20 (and your project) try setting Build Active Architectures Only to on.